# Enable/disable texture antialiasing inside the scene in DirectX debug mode

Tags: directx, antialiasing

I would like to display two primitives:

- The first displaying a texture with antialiasing
- The second displaying a texture without antialiasing

Here is my code to setup the texture before each primitive render:

```
device.SetTexture(0, texture);
if(antialiasing)
{
    device.SetSamplerState(0, SamplerState.MinFilter, TextureFilter.Linear);
    device.SetSamplerState(0, SamplerState.MagFilter, TextureFilter.Linear);
}
else
{
    device.SetSamplerState(0, SamplerState.MinFilter, TextureFilter.None);
    device.SetSamplerState(0, SamplerState.MagFilter, TextureFilter.None);
}
```

It works but if I use DirectX debug mode I get an exception with the *D3DERR_UNSUPPORTEDTEXTUREFILTER: Unsupported texture filter*

I'm using *SlimDX* but I think this code would crash anyway with C++ API.

Comment: So does this error come up for TextureFilter.Linear or TextureFilter.None? Are you using the reference rasterizer?

Comment: Both, but only to the second call of SetSamplerState (within the BeginScene/EndScene block). I don't use the reference rasterizer, what is it for?